# adding prepare statement before calling getconnection () function from the connection pool

Tags: spring, hibernate, hikaricp

I want to add a prepare statement before calling the getconnection() from my hibernate hikariCP connection pool.
the statement is dbms_session.set_identifier("Current User");

I've been trying to do so with spring AOP without any success.

Then i thought trying to wrap the hikariCP connection provider, but i can't find a good example or guidline how to do it

can someone help please ?

Comment: Just wrap the datasource, and in the `getConnection` call execute the query.

Comment: How this can be achieved with the hibernate wrapper ?

Comment: You are using Spring, just configure the datasource in spring, create a wrapper for `DataSource` and reimplement the `getCOnnection` method> Wouldn't use the wrapper if you can use spring.

Comment: can you guide me how to send the login name ?   I tried to send the user  authentication principal but, it makes me problem

Comment: I'm trying to take the details from the security context but, i'm not sure this is the way